# xamarin form json empty +await

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfFAe.jpg)I have an ASP.NET WebApi hosted in Azure. There is no HTTP Header based or Azure API authentication on it and fiddler sessions prove that the API is fully functional

In my Xamarin forms when i'm trying to have json file it is always empty there is a problem with await and task really i don't know

Comment: please do NOT post code as images.  Take the time to paste and properly format your code in the post.

Comment: your breakpoint is hit BEFORE that line executes.  You need to examine the value of json AFTER the line executes.  And you are storing the value in local variable that will be out of scope as soon as the method completes.

Comment: @Jason That should be an answer :-) not comment